# Google Sites API: OAuth2 for Java

Tags: google-sites

Is there any Java sample codes that allows Google Sites API to use OAuth2 credential?

I can't see any OAuth2 APIs at com.google.gdata.client.sites.SitesService (https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/client/sites/SitesService).

Answer (score 1):

I know why now. There is a missing library for gdata-media-1.0.jar =.='